# Google Consent API

Tags: google-cloud-healthcare

The samples and documentation for the Cloud Healthcare Consent API need a refresh.  For instance, when POST to attributeDefinitions?attributeDefinitionId=requester_identity
with BODY:
{
"description": "what groups are consented for access",
"category": "REQUEST",
"allowedValues": [
"fhirUser"
]
}

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "attribute definition ID  malformed, must match ^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,255}$",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

These are the values straight from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This was an error on my side.  The proxy was dropping the query string parameter.  The value in the documentation is correct.